# Properties Dialog Box

Tags: python

I am trying to add a button on the tool panel for material which should open the material editor in a dialog box, which should be resizeable.

I can do the button but am having trouble creating the dialog box.

I tried to Do this by making duplicate window and dislplaying the properties editor in full screen but it takes up the whole screen.

I can make simple scripts in blender but don' know how to this.

Any help is much apreciated.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Header  

bpy.ops.wm.window_duplicate()  
bpy.ops.screen.screen_full_area()  
bpy.context.area.type='PROPERTIES'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is where terminology is important (area vs. window). Your current Blender window is full screen, so duplicating that window results in *another* full screen window. You might have better success if you try the [`bpy.ops.screen.area_dupli()`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70a_release/bpy.ops.screen.html#bpy.ops.screen.area_dupli) operator and duplicate the area that contains the existing Properties Editor in your layout. The only caveat is that you need to first set that as your active area.

Comment: You can use a context override to avoid changing the active area! But I would actually try to find an existing area of a certain type first, and if there's none, duplicate the one with the largest area: http://www.pasteall.org/51468/python

Comment: Huh, it worked. Now how can I switch to material screen if an object is selected and I press the button.