# New window with Python API?

Tags: python, interface

How to create a new window with a certain dimensions (for example 40% of screen size) using Python API?

Functionality-wise similar to File > User Preferences — a new window shows up with User Preferences area type.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/9231/47

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Currently in Blender 2.79 the only way to manage windows through Python API is by `bpy.ops.screen.area_dupli()` and `bpy.ops.wm.window_duplicate()` operators.

But they add new screens to `bpy.data.screens`, which are not easy to remove.

And there is no way to resize created windows.

**UPDATE 1:**

In my particular case I can use window created by `userpref_show` operator, it's size is very close to what I need and it creates 'temp' screen which is deleted after window is closed, so I do not need to cleanup `bpy.data.screens` afterwards:

```
import bpy

# Call user prefs window
bpy.ops.screen.userpref_show("INVOKE_DEFAULT")

# Change area type
area = bpy.context.window_manager.windows[-1].screen.areas[0]
area.type = "TEXT_EDITOR"
```

**UPDATE 2:**

With `render.view_show` operator it is possible to set the exact size of created window by modifying render settings:

```
import bpy

# Modify render settings
render = bpy.context.scene.render
render.resolution_x = 640
render.resolution_y = 480
render.resolution_percentage = 100

# Modify preferences (to guaranty new window)
prefs = bpy.context.preferences
prefs.view.render_display_type = "WINDOW"

# Call image editor window
bpy.ops.render.view_show("INVOKE_DEFAULT")

# Change area type
area = bpy.context.window_manager.windows[-1].screen.areas[0]
area.type = "TEXT_EDITOR"

# Restore render settings and preferences
# render.resolution_x = original_value
# ...

# I also restore is_dirty tag which affects preferences autosave feature
# prefs.is_dirty = original_value
```

Comment: Interesting that it is just as easy to set up buttons in a panel to create editors as popups for specific uses - I made mine a small Image Editor and set it to Paint in the script, and this is actually useful. Thanks.

Comment: simple hack but works as expected, I'm looking a way to create multiple of the window, currently this code only allow only one instance of window

Comment: ah by adding as follow allow me to add a lot of windows with different type 

```python
import bpy

# Call user prefs window
bpy.ops.screen.userpref_show('INVOKE_DEFAULT')

# Change area type
area = bpy.context.window_manager.windows[-1].screen.areas[0]
area.type = 'TEXT_EDITOR'
bpy.ops.wm.window_duplicate()
area.type = 'CONSOLE'
```

Comment: @aditia I do not recommend this, each time you use `window_duplicate` operator it will add additional screen `temp.001` that will not be removed after you close the second window, which will mess up your workflow if you switch between screens as often as I do.

Comment: @MikhailRachinskiy ah I see, you're correct, using dupli make screen messier

Answer (score 6):

I have been struggeling with this as well and would like to share my solution. I wanted to be able to open several windows and change their layout in my script. `bpy.ops.screen.userpref_show()` opens a window with just a single area but it wouldn't allow me to open several windows and the windows would have the title "Blender User Preferences". `bpy.ops.wm.window_duplicate()` would allow me to open several windows and make them the same size as the current window, but it would open with my multi-area screen and produce a new screen everytime without removing it. This is my solution:

### A helper to create contexts for operator calls:

```
# Construct context
def context(window=None, screen=None, area=None, region=None):
    if window is None: window = C.window
    if screen is None: screen = window.screen
    if area is None: area = screen.areas[0]
    if region is None: region = area.regions[0]
    return {'window': window, 'screen': screen, 'area': area, 'region': region}
```

### Wrappers for Window, Screen and Area:

```
# Window class wrapper
class Window:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window

    # Get window screen
    def get_screen(self):
        return Screen(self.window.screen)

    # Create new window
    @classmethod
    def new(cls, screen_name):
        bpy.ops.wm.window_duplicate()
        window = cls(C.window_manager.windows[-1])
        window.get_screen().set_name(screen_name).join_all()
        return window

# Screen class wrapper
class Screen:
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen

    # Get name
    def get_name(self, name):
        return self.screen.name

    # Set name
    def set_name(self, name):
        self.screen.name = name

        # Return self for method chaining
        return self

    # Get scene
    def get_scene(self):
        return self.screen.scene

    # Set scene
    def set_scene(self, scene):
        self.screen.scene = scene

        # Return self for method chaining
        return self

    # Get area
    def area_at(self, index):
        return Area(self.screen.areas[index])

    # Split area and return new one
    def split_area(self, area, dir, factor):
        # Set direction
        if 'vertical'.startswith(dir.lower()): dir = 'VERTICAL'
        elif 'horizontal'.startswith(dir.lower()): dir = 'HORIZONTAL'
        else: raise ValueError("Invalid direction \"%s\""%dir)

        bpy.ops.screen.area_split(
            context(screen=self.screen, area=area.area),
            direction=dir, factor=factor
        )
        return Area(self.screen.areas[-1])

    # Join areas and return success status
    def join_areas(self, area1, area2):
        # Try joining areas
        result = bpy.ops.screen.area_join(context(screen=self.screen),
            min_x=area1.x, min_y=area1.y,
            max_x=area2.x, max_y=area2.y
        )

        # Return eliminated area
        return ('FINISHED' in result)

    # Join all areas
    def join_all(self):
        # Create area index
        index = self.AreaIndex(self.screen.areas)

        # Join all areas
        for i in range(index.count):
            for key in index.x:
                for a1, a2 in index.x_pair_iterator(key):
                    if self.join_areas(a1, a2):
                        index.remove_area(a2)
                        break
            for key in index.y:
                for a1, a2 in index.y_pair_iterator(key):
                    if self.join_areas(a1, a2):
                        index.remove_area(a2)
                        break
            if index.count <= 1: break

        # Return self for method chaining
        return self

    # Area index for area joining
    class AreaIndex:
        # Create area index
        def __init__(self, areas):
            # Create index maps
            self.x = {}
            self.y = {}
            self.count = len(areas)

            # Insert areas into indices
            for area in areas:
                if not area.x in self.x: self.x[area.x] = []
                self.x[area.x].append(area)
                if not area.y in self.y: self.y[area.y] = []
                self.y[area.y].append(area)

            # Sort area lists
            for key in self.x: self.x[key].sort(key=lambda a: a.y)
            for key in self.y: self.y[key].sort(key=lambda a: a.x)

        # Remove area from index
        def remove_area(self, area):
            self.x[area.x].remove(area)
            self.y[area.y].remove(area)
            self.count -= 1

        # Iterate over area pairs for x key
        def x_pair_iterator(self, key):
            for i in range(len(self.x[key]) - 1):
                yield (self.x[key][i], self.x[key][i + 1])

        # Iterate over area pairs for x key
        def y_pair_iterator(self, key):
            for i in range(len(self.y[key]) - 1):
                yield (self.y[key][i], self.y[key][i + 1])

# Area class wrapper
class Area:
    def __init__(self, area):
        self.area = area

    # Get area type
    def get_type(self):
        return self.area.type

    # Set area type
    def set_type(self, type):
        self.area.type = type

        # Return self for method chaining
        return self
```

### Create a window with two areas and remove unused screens:

```
SCREEN_NAME = "temp"

# Create new window
window = Window.new(SCREEN_NAME)
screen = window.get_screen().set_scene(D.scenes['Test'])

# Setup areas
node_area = screen.area_at(0).set_type('NODE_EDITOR')
movie_area = screen.split_area(node_area, 'v', 0.7).set_type('CLIP_EDITOR')

# Get used screens
used_screens = set(
    w.screen for w in C.window_manager.windows
    if w.screen.name.startswith(SCREEN_NAME)
)

# Delete unused screens
screen_backup = C.window.screen
for s in D.screens:
    if s.name.startswith(SCREEN_NAME) and s not in used_screens:
        bpy.ops.screen.delete(context(screen=s))
C.window.screen = screen_backup
```