# blender 2.8 how duplicate view3d area into new window from script

Tags: scripting, 3d-view

Is there a way to duplicate view3d area into a new window from a script?
This is how it's done through the UI: [blender docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/areas.html#duplicate-area-into-new-window).
I want to have a separate window with only the 3d viewport.

found this operator:

```
bpy.ops.screen.area_dupli()
```

but it gives:

```
ERROR (wm.operator): /home/sources/blender-release/source/blender/windowmanager/intern/wm_event_system.c:1459 wm_operator_invoke: invalid operator call 'SCREEN_OT_area_dupli'
```

found this for blender 2.79:
[New window with Python API?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81974/new-window-with-python-api)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator still works in 2.80, but you need two parameters:

1. A custom context that tells the operator what area should be used for the new window
2. The correct execution context

The custom context can be created by modifying a copy of the current one. The area object for the 3D view can be found by iterating through `bpy.context.screen.areas` and checking for the `type` to be `'VIEW_3D'`.

Executing `bpy.ops.screen.area_dupli(context)` will not work properly, because `EXEC_DEFAULT` is used as the default execution context. When this is the case `event->customdata` is `NULL` (see [`screen_ops.c`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/screen/screen_ops.c$1331)) which results in the operator returning `PASS_THROUGH` and no window being created. The solution is to add `INVOKE_DEFAULT` as argument, which is exactly what the button in the user interface does.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context.copy()

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        context['area'] = area
        bpy.ops.screen.area_dupli(context, 'INVOKE_DEFAULT')
        break
```

Comment: Sorry, it took a long time for me to notice. I took a break from it as it was a roadblock to my addon development. I'll test those out as soon as I can. Thanks very much for the detailed and clear answer.