# blender python api custom GUI

Tags: python, customization, operator

Blender version 2.83
I need create dialog window with User. Now i'm using `context.wm.invoke_popup`
but problem that This dialog window close when cursor to far from it and not resible.
Can i create GUI with Blender python API ?

Or give some info What do I need to do to prevent the dialog window from closing
`context.wm.invoke_props_dialog` is bad because there button 'ok' i don't need this.
My operator:

```
class EXAMPLE_OT_window(Operator):
    bl_idname = 'example.window'
    bl_label = 'Example'
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', }
    bl_description = 'example_description'

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_popup(self, width=300)

    def execute(self, context):
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.separator()
        layout.label(text=self.bl_label)
        layout.separator()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using panels in 2.8+**

It's my opinion that many (including my previous self) get over enamoured with invoking modal dialog props dialogs.

Currently question code has some empty operator (execution wise) that is basically  a draw method. Often I see code where the functionality of the operator used to draw a popup could be replaced entirely by a group property and update methods on the individual properties, hence may as well put in panel code.

IMO if you want a nice stable UI use a panel

Since the advent of 2.8 there is  the ability to

- [absolutely size panel content](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.ui_units_x)
- Popup a panel with an operator `wm.popup_panel(...)`
- Popup a panel from draw method (no operator `layout.popover(...)`
- Make child panels.

Here is an example which I've demonstrated in text editor.  (based from good old Hello World Panel template)

In the UI N panel (`context.region == 'UI'`) the x ui width is set to 0 making the add cube operator button the width of the panel, if invoked from the FOOTER region then the panel is 20 wide.

[image]

```
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "TEXT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'TEXT_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'


    def draw(self, context):
        print(context.region.type)
        layout = self.layout
        layout.ui_units_x = 0 if context.region.type == 'UI' else 20
        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        
        row.label(text="Hello world!", icon='WORLD_DATA')

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Active object is: " + obj.name)
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(obj, "name")

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")

def draw_panel(self, context):
    op = self.layout.operator("wm.call_panel")
    op.name = "TEXT_PT_hello"
    self.layout.popover("TEXT_PT_hello")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bpy.types.TEXT_HT_footer.append(draw_panel)
    register()
```

Note: Given the desire is to have "popup" not close when mousing away, and be resizable consider opening a new window as discussed here

[New window with Python API?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81974/new-window-with-python-api)

Comment: Thank you. Can i change button text of "OK" button in 'invoke_props_dialog' to another word ?
Can i create a custom space_area with my buttons, labeles etc like 'PROPERTIES', 'VIEW_3D', 'TEXT_EDITOR' ?