# Can we create custom tools UI like the import window we have in blender instead of using Panel?

Tags: python

I am looking to create some custom tools, I used blender Panel to create those tools but they have some limitations with them like getting closed if I click somewhere else on the blender window, can't we create something like this Import Window ourselves as it seems to overcome all those limitations.

[image]

EDIT :

[image]

Thanks & Regards

Comment: UI of Blender is created with a specific philosophy. The idea is that there should be no blocking popups and floating windows that block other stuff, the user should be able to see all UI while working and should not spend time and effort managing floating windows but instead direct that energy to work. So... Another window is sort of against the idea of Blender's UI design and that also limits tools for this in its Python API. It also makes sense to consider keeping UI of your add-ons consistent with existing Blender's UI and ideas behind it.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Hey thanks for your response, it's just i have one question as we can see  for the import window we are contradicting with Blender's UI rules, so is there anyway we can do it by ourselves or it's something like pre designed and we can't copy this feature using Python API.

Comment: Also it's a bit hard to understand what exactly you mean, when you say that you tried "Blender Panel". [Panels](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/tabs_panels.html#panels) can be located in many places of Blender's UI. They don't necessarily close when you click away.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81974/new-window-with-python-api

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Sorry about that I have added an image of a sample that i have created , but as soon as i click somewhere it's getting closed , so this is what i meant can i create this panel something like the import window which doesn't close even on clicking somewhere else.

Comment: It's quite usual to put add-ons in the 'n-panel'/[Sidebar](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/regions.html) but everyone is doing that so for people using many addons it's getting a bit crowded there. If you can think of a more suitable place for your tools, you should use other parts of the UI, but there might be a reason Sidebar is so popular...

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys,  Yes to an extent Thanks for your response